# Почему в csv распаршенного xlsx вместо даты из ячейки - какие-то числа. как их привести к обычному формату даты?

Tags: php, парсер, xml, дата, xlsx

Разархивировал Excel файл библиотекой unzip, в итоге у меня в ячейках, где были даты - в csv стоят числа. Например, вот что произошло с С2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

01.10.2021 превратилось в 44470. Как перевести обратно, чтобы уложить в бд?

Comment: И при чем здесь PHP?

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Просто пишу парсер xlsx на php... подойдут решения, которые для него релевантны...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137007/15035314

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо за помощь огромное! Помогло!